# Relative and absolute positioning

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to place content after an absolute positioned div that's within a relative positioned div. if I don't know the height of the relative positioned div.

Basically, I have this configuration ...

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:100;">
    <div style="position:absolute; top:100; left:100;">
<div>
```

(... and I'd like to place content here)

Since this is dynamic, I don't have the actual height of the relative div. so I can't place it within this container's CSS.

I created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/o7k2dpdz/) to illustrate what I'm trying to do. I left an artificial 500px as my height but I'd like to remove this and have it still work if possible.

Comment: What kind of content?

Comment: No. You must use height otherwise your background would not be appeared to whole container even if absolute div is visible. Is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use the `position:absolute;` approach for this kind of layout.

Here is a solution example i made without absolute positioning

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimshik/o7k2dpdz/1/)

Hope this is what you intended to create.

Comment: Very clever Dimshik, but in my case I will need absolute positioning. I'm placing objects using a shortest column approach. I've been able to resolve this using Javascript. I calculate the tallest column and use this px measurement as my container height, which appears to work well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The above only illustrates one column, but in my larger app. I'm using several.